# dealing with jquery files?

Tags: jquery, performance, file, cdn

i have quite a lot of jquery files, like around 6 files, how can i sort them out. shall i put them all in one file, and upload it to a CDN, taking in account page loads etc.

p.s. im also using google jquery cdn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put them in one file, compress them 'if not already compressed' and use your CDN, will give you the best loading performance.

Comment: thanks, i know this is a stupid question, but can compression ruin your syntax!! thanks